# Immersion water heater in a metal cup

Tags: safety, electrical

I am creating a non-profit product for charity and I have a simple electrical question.

I plan to place a small single cup immersion water heater inside a stainless steel cup. But I am going to have a plastic safety cover that goes around the outside of the cup. And a sticker on the cup that says "Be careful not to touch the water or metal cup, while the heater is in use."

Does this sound safe enough to sell on ebay and amazon?

Thanks so much for any advice.

ps: I live in Thailand, so it might take me a while to answer any questions, cause of the time difference.

Comment: What might happen if they do touch it?

Comment: I don't know a lot about electricity, but if the electric source is not grounded correctly, they can get a shock. In some smaller countries there are no standards for grounding correctly. Maybe older houses in the USA also?

Comment: So, you are asking if a sticker with a message is safe enough to prevent people from possibly dying from touching something that they usually do?

Comment: Not just a sticker, but a plastic cover. People are using these immersion water heaters all over the world, every day. I don't think anyone has died. I am at least adding a little protection.

Comment: So I think as long as I have a plastic cover, and someone can not the metal or water, it is safe. - I guess my question was, if there is anything else that I don't understand, that could be a problem?

Comment: Your sticker will not protect you from product liability laws, at least not in the U.S. You don't **think** anyone has died?? You are adding a **little** protection? What if the plastic cover gets a hole or a crack in it? Please don't do this.

Comment: Is it an isolated immersion resistor, or one of these suicide machines where the resistive wire goes directly into the water, or worse which run the AC current directly through the water like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EViyccc2t9w&t=5m)?

Answer (score 4):

> And a sticker on the cup that says "Be careful not to touch the water or metal cup, while the heater is in use."

A sticker is no substitute for electrical safety. It doesn't protect children or people who can't read or stupid people (who may be smart enough to sue you).

If proper grounding cannot be guaranteed then double-insulated safety category is required. Most water heating elements have a metal outer jacket so you are unlikely to be able to achieve double-insulated safety rating for your device.

> So I think as long as I have a plastic cover, and someone can not the metal or water, it is safe.

Electricity and water are a dangerous combination. You have to think of every possible thing that could go wrong and address it in a risk assessment. From that you modify the design to eliminate the risk. In this case a faulty element or wet cable could be lethal.

The general advice here would be to avoid getting into manufacturing something for sale that might - highly likely in this case - risk harm and you and your charity facing legal action.

Answer (score 2):

I got one of these from China recently and have used it in a metal cup a few times. I have got two 220v shocks from touching the cup when it was plugged in. No instructions came with it. I knew they could cause fires, but I had to find out the hard way about the lack of grounding causing dangerous shocks.